# problems of using jquery tab slider In ember.js

Tags: jquery-plugins, ember.js

I would like to ember.js use jquery tab slider, this is my View, I implement`didInsertElement` hook, but which seems to have problems

```
Ember.Slider = Em.View.extend
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile([
        " <div id='top_press_banner'> "
        "   <ul class='switcher'> "
        "     {{#each topFive  itemController='new'}} "
        "       <li {{bindAttr tabslider-ref='this.id'}}>{{this.title}}</li> "
        "     {{/each}} "
        "   </ul> "
        "   {{#each topFive itemController='new'}} "
        "     <div {{bindAttr tabslider-name='this.id'}}> "
        "       <img {{bindAttr src='this.zoomTopFiveCover'}}> "
        "       <div class='item-caption'> "
        "         <h4>{{title}}</h4> "
        "         <p>{{description}}</p> "
        "       </div> "
        "     </div> "
        "   {{/each}} "
        " </div> "
        ].join("\n"))
    didInsertElement: ->
        console.log @$().html()
        $("#top_press_banner").tabSlider()
```

`topFive` is an array in the controller

Output log:

```
<div id="top_press_banner"> 
<ul class="switcher"> 
    <script id="metamorph-1-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>      <script id="metamorph-1-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script> 
 </ul> 
 <script id="metamorph-2-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script> <script id="metamorph-2-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script> 
</div>
```

When `tabSlider` method is invoked, `$ ("# top_press_banner")` within the html has not been inserted into the dom, who told me to change how to do?

Comment: how to get DOM elements after view changed in ember js

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `afterRender` Queue in the Ember Run Loop. Look for an explanation here: http://mavilein.github.io/javascript/2013/08/01/Ember-JS-After-Render-Event/

```
App.YourView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement : function(){
    this._super();
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function(){
        // perform your jQuery logic here
    });
  }
});
```

PS: Code highlighting does not seem to work on mobile.

Comment: thanks for your concern, but the output `console.log $ (" # top_press_banner "). Html ()` is still the same